# How to get specific element from a JSON file in Python?

Tags: python, json

I am using The Guardian's API to get JSON data and now I want a specific element from the JSON data entry. How do I do that?

I am making the following GET request

```
url = 'http://content.guardianapis.com/search?from-date=2016-01-02&to-date=2016-01-02&order-by=newest&show-fields=all&page-size=1&api-key=API-KEY.
```

And now I want webTitle from the JSON data. So I am doing as follows:

```
response = requests.get(url)
response = response.content
response = json.loads(response)
content = response['response']['results']['webTitle']
```

But I am getting `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str` error.

However, `content = response['response']['results']`works correctly.

Here is a spanshot of JSON data.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
response = request.get(url).json()
content = response['response']['results'][index]['webTitle']
```

### Edit

Yes as Sudheesh Singanamalla suggests, results is a list and you You'd have to access a given index to get corresponding `webTitle`

Comment: This wouldn't work since `results` is a list. You'd have to access a given index `[0],[1]` etc..

Answer (score 1):

We get this error when we mistake a list with a dictionary. Seems like 'results' is actually a list with dictionary as its first item. Do the following instead.

```
content = response['response']['results'][0]['webTitle']
```

And obviously I assumed you have one item in the 'results' list only. If it has multiple items, iterate over the list.

Answer (score 1):

`response['response']['results']` provides you with a list of dictionaries. `[{},{},...]` where each dictionary contains the following in your example:

```
{id:'', type:'', sectionid:'', .... }
```

If you want the list of all the `webTitle` in the results you'd have to iterate over the list obtained from `response['response']['results']` and select the `webTitle` or any other required key in the resulting dictionary. Here's an example

```
webTitleList = []
# Make the request for the JSON
results = response['response']['results']
for result in results:
    webTitleList.append(result['webTitle'])
# Now the webTitleList contains the list of all the webTitles in the returned json
```

However, you can also simplify the selection of the `webTitle` by using list comprehension on `results`. There are numerous examples on StackOverflow for the same.

Comment: Please mark one of the answers as accepted in case they helped you so that the question could be marked as closed.

Answer (score 0):

`results` is a list. Iterate over it to fetch the required value.

**Ex:**

```
for i in response['response']['results']:
    print(i['webTitle'])
```